# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emitFile

Tags: typeerror, undefined, render, multer

So I created an image upload in node js using multer and grid fs and deployed I deployed it on render, it was woking perfectly fine untile after some months later and i started having is error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emitFile (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage/lib/gridfs.js:306:31)

so I tried troubleshooting, I ran it on localhost and I was able to upload image without any error, but each time i try to use the deployed url (i.e the one hosted on render) i keep getting the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6W7k.png)